# Independent from others?

Tags: sentence-construction

> In a semi-direct consensus democracy, on the other hand, party
> competition is low because elections cannot lead to a change of roles
> between government and opposition. The system places its trust in the
> final control by the people over all important issues. Legitimacy
> comes from the most important decisions being taken by the people
> directly. Proportionality in elections and mutual adjustment in
> legislative decision-making favour the idea of ‘no single winner takes
> everything, everybody wins something’. In direct democracy, voting is
> on a single issue at a time, and each case produces different winning
> coalitions, which are barely foreseeable by the political elites. **A
> popular vote, even when settling a fundamental issue, involves just
> one clear decision independent from the others.** The Swiss government,
> free from the fear of not being re-elected, will not spend much time
> on programmatic strategy. The narrow limits of manoeuvre imposed by an
> all-party government and the permanent risk of a referendum defeat
> drastically curtail any effort to design comprehensive programmes and,
> at least in domestic policies, allow for incremental progress only.
>
> *- Swiss Democracy bu Wolf Linder*

In the sentence I emphasized, what does "others" refer to? To other decisions? Or what? I cannot understand.

Answer (score 1):

"Others" refers to "other decisions". The sentence in bold could be expressed:

> A popular vote, even when settling a fundamental issue, involves just one clear decision independent from the other decisions.

That is, a popular vote could be a "yes" or "no" choice, resolving one issue, which is therefore independent from other decisions on other issues.

Comment: I agree, although I did wonder whether the sentence could be interpreted to mean **other issues**.

Comment: I also went through the same thought process, but landed on **other decisions** which could be extended to **other decisions on (other) issues** essentially.